# Is this a bug in the comment section on the Stack Overflow site?

Tags: discussion, bug

I recently saw a question and it showed the below image.

It seems that the code background color is overflowing the div and showing in another portion.

Maybe it is a bug or if it isn’t a bug then please explain why this behaviour is happening.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

The question: *[How to render multiple Component-type variables through a template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69730632/how-to-render-multiple-component-type-variables-through-a-template)*

Image:

[image]

Comment: The "bug" is the user trying to use comments for multiline indented code...